# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid Pivot table

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, interactive-grid

Oracle Apex interactive grid pivot
total row should be grey highlight.

I have created an interactive grid using pivot option and I have a line with name of **TOTAL** in `FINISH_UNIT` column.

Now I want to set that if Grid found **TOTAL** text in `FINISH_UNIT` column then change the Row color with **GREY** instead of white.

I have tried to use CSS but unable to adjust this. How can I set this condition in my interactive grid if there is css code? Please guide with example or if there is builtin option in interactive grid.

Whole data fetch from SQL script

Here is a query for reference (note this is grouping query with adding total)

```
select SBU_FINISH,
nvl(FINISH_UNIT, 'Total') FINISH_UNIT,
--FINISH_UNIT,
OMS_MONTH,
oms_month_no,
sum(ORDER_QTY) ORDER_QTY,
sum(COUNT_STYLE) COUNT_STYLE
from ( select * from MY_TABLE
WHERE TO_DATE(TO_char(oms_date), 'MM-DD-YYYY') between TO_DATE(:P7_DATE1, 'MM-DD-YYYY') and TO_DATE(:P7_DATE2, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
AND (to_char(SOLD_TO_ORG_ID) IN ( SELECT regexp_substr(:P7_BRAND,'[^,]+',1,level) FROM dual CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:P7_BRAND,'[^,]+',1,level) IS NOT NULL) OR :P7_BRAND IS NULL)
AND (to_char(PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID) IN ( SELECT regexp_substr(:P7_CLIENTS,'[^,]+',1,level) FROM dual CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:P7_CLIENTS,'[^,]+',1,level) IS NOT NULL) OR :P7_CLIENTS IS NULL)
)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((SBU_FINISH,FINISH_UNIT,OMS_MONTH,oms_month_no),(SBU_FINISH,OMS_MONTH,oms_month_no))
```

Screen shot attached for reference.
[image]

Comment: waiting for solution..

Answer (score 0):

I believe interactive grids don't have a pivot option, it's interactive reports that do. In case this is what you meant here is my solution for this.

First, add a fake column in your query that analyzes your condition

```
(CASE
   WHEN FINISH_UNIT = 'Total' THEN 'GREY' 
   ELSE 'WHITE'
END) AS COLOR
```

Next up go to the columns that you paint and you should have a Column Formating field with a HTML expression
There you can use html to format and reference your columns.

```
<span style="background-color:#COLOR#;">#COLUMN_NAME#</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on highlighting row where finish unit column is greater than 0